# How find User ID from a list of Facebook User URLs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm a little out of my element here so forgive me if I'm not asking a the question correctly, but I'm trying to take a list of Facebook User URLs and find the User ID. I found another SE post that showed how to do this for one user, which basically took a graph.facebook url and appended the User URL to the end like so: http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20url%2C%20id%2C%20type%2C%20site%20from%20object_url%20where%20url%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F[firstname.lastname]%22

Which outputs:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "url": "http://www.facebook.com/firstname.lastname",
         "id": [userID],
         "type": "profile",
         "site": "www.facebook.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I can make a batch request with big list of URLs, and easily store those user IDs in an excel sheet. Unfortunately I tried reading up on the facebook developers API overview but I don't really understand any of it, nor how to use cURL or urllib. Would anyone be able to help me out?

Comment: FQL is going away end of April 2015, and in API v2 the `username` field has been removed; meaning: There is no way to do this any more, and that is on purpose. Your app is only meant to deal with data of users that actively connected with it, and not with any kind of user data feed into it from ”outside”.

Comment: And btw., the format of such user profile addresses does not have to be `firstname.lastname`, users are free to chose any arbitrary moniker for their profile address. (Apart from ones Facebook has “reserved” already for special purposes, or those that are in use already.)

Comment: Thanks CBroe - I actually figured out how to do it without using an API. My goal was literally just to get a list of the user ids of my page's fans. All I needed to do was to visit this URL https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=[page ID here] and the user names and ids are in the code so I just wrote a quick xpath to grab them all. Thanks!

Comment: What do you need those ids for anyway …? You are aware that you are not allowed to “reward” people in any way for liking your page, or contact them simply based on the fact that they are fans of your page, I hope.

Comment: Ha. And I just found out that you can't create a custom ad audience with User IDs unless you have an app associated with those users. I wanted to just exclude my page fans from my ads, but clearly i have been going about this all wrong, and I am a dodo. Have a wonderful day guys.

Comment: You can omit page fans from ads targeting already, it's one of the built-in targeting options and doesn't need any collection of data on your part

Comment: @Igy, I'm not sure if that's true. You can exclude a custom audience or you can exclude a lookalike audience. I can create a lookalike audience based on my page fans, but that creates an audience of 2m people - and if those are the people who are similar to those who like my page, then I actually want to target those people, not exclude them. 
If you could correct me I would be  very happy?

Comment: Matt: In Ads Manager, when selecting targeting options, it's under Connections: "Only people not connected to <PAGE NAME>
If you're using the Ads API, it's the `excluded_connections` field of the `targeting_spec`
This is one of the basic targeting options, it's been around a lot longer than custom audiences

Comment: Got it. Once again I prove to be a dodo. Thanks Igy for your help and patience.